# Compute the first day to display in a calendar view in android 2.2

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to generate an array of integers that contains the days of month that need to be displayed in the current month view. For example the current month view will have 26th August in the first row column.

[image]

What is the easiest way to get the integers to be displayed in this above grid in java using Calendar and Date classes?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is interesting for me, so I've created solution:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class CalendarTable {

    private static List<Integer> daysPositions = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    static {
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.SUNDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.MONDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.TUESDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.WEDNESDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.THURSDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.FRIDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.SATURDAY );
    }

    public static void viewCalendar( Date date ) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime( date );

        calendar.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 );
        // day of week for first date of month
        int firstDateOfMonthDay = calendar.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );
        int weekOfFirstDate = calendar.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR );

        int lastDateOfMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );
        calendar.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDateOfMonth );
        // day of week for last date of month
        int lastDateOfMonthDay = calendar.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );
        int weekOfLastDate = calendar.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR );

        calendar.roll( Calendar.MONTH, false );
        int lastDateOfPrevMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );

        int weeksToDisplay = weekOfLastDate - weekOfFirstDate + 1;
        int[] days = new int[weeksToDisplay * 7];

        int firstDayPosition = daysPositions.indexOf( firstDateOfMonthDay );

        // fill previous month
        int x = lastDateOfPrevMonth;
        for ( int i = firstDayPosition - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            days[i] = x--;
        }

        // fill current month
        for ( int i = 1; i < lastDateOfMonth + 1; i++ ) {
            days[firstDayPosition - 1 + i] = i;
        }

        // fill next month
        int j = 1;
        for ( int i = lastDateOfMonth + firstDayPosition; i < days.length; i++ ) {
            days[i] = j++;
        }

        // display calendar
        // ( here you may extract data into your structure )
        for ( int i = 0; i < days.length; i++ ) {
            if ( i % 7 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print( days[i] + "\t" );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        viewCalendar( new Date() );
    }

}
```

After executing, you'll get output (for example - current month view):

```
26  27  28  29  30  31  1   
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
9   10  11  12  13  14  15  
16  17  18  19  20  21  22  
23  24  25  26  27  28  29  
30  1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Also, in some calendars - first day of week is Monday, so you may fill `daysPositions` in such way:

```
    static {
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.MONDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.TUESDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.WEDNESDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.THURSDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.FRIDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.SATURDAY );
        daysPositions.add( Calendar.SUNDAY ); // move Sunday to the end of week
    }
```

After this manipulation, for current month view you'll get:

```
27  28  29  30  31  1   2   
3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  
17  18  19  20  21  22  23  
24  25  26  27  28  29  30  
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it.. I came up with a smaller solution.. I get the DAY_OF_WEEK and WEEK_OF_MONTH and calculate the difference from current date in milliseconds. Then move on to next day by adding number of millisec/day. That saves me some lines of code. I'll add this answer later.. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Ronnie,
Have you optimised this solution? If yes, please share it.